# Format currency

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Hi i have function to convert number to Localize price format.
But when i send 2000 i'll get bak   2.000,00 EUR

id like to get  2.000 EUR   (without cents)

and formated to  2 000,-

```
-(NSString *) formatPrice:(NSString *)myPrice
{
    NSNumber *price = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[myPrice intValue]];
    NSLocale *priceLocale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"de_DE"] autorelease]; // get the locale from your SKProduct

NSNumberFormatter *currencyFormatter = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[currencyFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];

[currencyFormatter setLocale:priceLocale];

NSString *currencyString = [currencyFormatter internationalCurrencySymbol]; // EUR, GBP, USD...

NSString *format = [currencyFormatter positiveFormat];

format = [format stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"¤" withString:currencyString];
// ¤ is a placeholder for the currency symbol
[currencyFormatter setPositiveFormat:format];

NSString *myPriceTitle = [currencyFormatter stringFromNumber:price];

return myPriceTitle;
}
```

thx

Answer (score 3):

Set the separator to @" " (a space) and the max fraction to zero. I think this should do the trick.

```
[formatter setCurrencyGroupingSeparator:@" "];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:0];
```

Comment: You're welcome vosy :) Would appreciate it if you could mark this off as answered. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Slightly better idea may be setting `if([price integerValue] == [price doubleValue])[formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:0];` Because this will format your price correctly with or without cents depending on actual price.